# Sort model records based on values in related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, relationship

I currently sort member records using in the members model file:

```
default_scope -> { order(:organization_id, :username) }
```

Organizations and members have a 1:many relationship. Instead of ordering on basis of organization_id I would like to order members on basis of the name of the organization, which is a column in the organization model. How should I do this?

I tried the lines below but this doesn't work; it only seems to accept variables from within the same model and not from models with which it has a relationship.

```
default_scope -> { order(:organization.name, :username) }
default_scope -> { order(organization.name, :username) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.includes`

```
default_scope -> { includes(:organization).order('organizations.name , username') }
```

Comment: Using that line, all sorts of tests all fail with the message `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'organizations' was not found on Member; perhaps you misspelled it?`. The association is setup properly though.  Since a member has 1 organization, I also tried it with `organization` instead of `organization*s*` but then I got error messages saying `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: organization.name: SELECT  "members"."id" ... etc. `

Comment: Oh, try edited one.  i have updated `includes(:organizations)` to includes(:organization). Try now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code:

`default_scope -> { includes(:organizations).order('organizations.name , username') }`